# Disable background app refresh for ONLY Messages app

Tags: battery, messages, ios

iOS 10 has made the Messages app drain my wife's iPhone 6's battery.

It uses up about 40% of her battery and most of that is background time.

How can I turn off background refresh for ONLY Messages?

(Not looking for a solution that turns off all background refreshes.)

Comment: As a sidenote, does anyone know if iOS 10.2 will fix this problem.

Comment: iOS 10.2 _may_ fix this problem by virtue of the fact it will force a restart of her device (as suggested in my answer). The only changes to Messages in iOS 10.2 are: (1) A new love and celebration full screen effect in Messages, and (2) It fixes an issue that sometimes prevented the keyboard from displaying in Messages.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to address the symptom, rather than the problem. To be clear, Messages should not be using up that much battery power. I suggest the following:

- Restart your wife's iPhone by holding down the Power and Home buttons simultaneously for about 10 seconds until you see the Apple logo
- Wait for her iPhone battery stats to refresh.

**NOTE:**
This may take up to a day - typically it will need to be plugged back into a charger and fully charged and then removed and used normally for a few hours up to a day before the battery stats will refresh.

Once you've done this, let us know if your wife is still having this problem.

Comment: We had already tried a normal reboot (hold down power). I will try with a hard reboot (hold down power and home).

Comment: @Vaccano Sorry, that's what I meant - a hard reboot. I've amended my answer to make this clearer.